# How to create an Elapsed Time function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to see the elapsed time in my game all the time. I want to be able to put it in "Time", it doesn't have to be formatted or anything. In seconds would be great.

```
document.getElementById("round_score").innerHTML = "Score: "+round_score+" | High Score: "+high_score+" | Elapsed Time: "+time;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a Date at the start like this:

```
var start = new Date();
```

Then when you want to find the elapsed time subtract start from now like

```
(new Date() - start ) / 1000
```

So putting it all together

```
var start = new Date();
var elapsed = (new Date() - start ) / 1000;
document.getElementById("round_score").innerHTML = "Score: "+round_score+" | High Score: "+high_score+" | Elapsed Time: "+elapsed;
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want to update the elapsed time in a loop? So I always get the elapsed time instead of once?

Comment: @CarlosMenzoni. Please clean up after yourself :-))  If DanWalmsley's post has answered your question, please check the answer as accepted. Otherwise your question unnecessarily remains on the "unanswered" queue. Thanks!